# Why some cli programs don't return arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, gnu

There are some cli-utilities that, when executed, the shell doesn't save the arguments you give to the command(**$1**,**$2**,**$@** etc.).
Is there a precise reason? Some examples are ls, dd..

Comment: I do not understand. How does `dd` or `ls` doesn't "save" variables? Which cli utilities do "save" variables in the ""variables""? How do they do that? The `$1`, `$2`, `$@` have a meaning when interpreted by the shell, it's not part of "utilities".

Comment: I'm bad-explaining myself. I was saying that the shell doesn't save the arguments you give in input to these utilities.

Comment: Why would it do that? When does the shell save arguments when you give them as input to which utilities? I mean, the current answer you can get to `Is there a precise reason?`: Yes, it's specified that shell shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for `!!:1`, `!!:2`, and so on which expand to arguments of the previous commands. See History Expansion in the [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) for more details.

Whereas, `$1`, `$2`, and `$@` refer to nth arguments passed in to the currently running script.

Comment: Thank you.. I'm newbie to bash and I've confused the two things.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if I was able to help you answer your question.